# How does Google Play and App Store download count work?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, google-play, app-store

my company is studying whether or not we should create an app for our portals. I found it hard to find information regarding the download count at Google's and Apple's app stores.

If one app store says 500K+ downloads, does it mean unique devices, unique users (by Google Account or Apple ID), total downloads or something else?

Imagine that you have a mobile and a tablet and you are logged in with the same account in both devices. You download an APP in your mobile and uninstalled it. One week later you installed it again in your mobile and also installed it in your tablet.

How many downloads will be added to the count in app store? Could you share some source confirming the answer?

[image]

Comment: On Google Play you have total number of downloads, so the counter is always increasing (but multiple downloads from same user should not add up). App Store AFAIK does not provide download count to the public.

Comment: @DerekK hi. And how are you defining "same user" ? Is that by Google Account or device ID?